# Is the identity $\rho=\sum_m M_m\rho M^t_m$ possible for measurement operators with $\sum_m M_m^t M_m=I$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

Nielsen and Chuang quantum information book has the following identity
$$\rho=\sum_m M_m\rho M^t_m$$
Where $M_m$ are measurement operators and $\sum M^t_m M_m=I$.

I suspect it must be a typo. I think that $\rho$ on the left hand side cannot be the same on the right hand side.
Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Which page....?

Comment: Page 101, equation 2.152

Comment: This looks like a typo. From the text, $\rho$ on the left should be the state after measurement (but the outcomes are discarded), and the one on the right is the state before measurement.

Comment: Which edition? Did you check the errata?

Comment: Thank you, guys. I did not check the errata. It's the 2010 edition. Thanks to your comments, I'm sure it must be a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M_m$ be operators such that $\rho=\sum_m M_m \rho M_m^\dagger$ for all $\rho$, and $\sum_m M_m^\dagger M_m=I$. These identities hold true iff they correspond to the identity channel, which is true iff each $M_m$ is proportional to the identity. See [this related post on qc.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/25917/55) for more details on how to prove this.

To be clear, Kraus operators should involve Hermitian conjugates, not transpositions. So either your ${\bullet}^t$ is a weird notation to denote Hermitian conjugate, or there is some underlying assumption that the matrices are real and thus these coincide. I'm assuming that you're asking about why one can have the overall operation to be an identity, rather than about the transpose/Hermitian conjugate bit.

Comment: What does it mean to "assume that the M_n are Kraus operators"?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I mean... exactly what it says? If you're trying to say that it's obvious that the set of $M_n$ are indeed Kraus operators of a channel, I agree with that. Modulo the transpose which should be a Hermitian conjugate I suppose, I was just kinda assuming $t$ to be a weird way to denote Hermitian conjugate, and/or there being an underlying assumption that the matrices are real

Comment: Isn't any matrix a Kraus operator (or rather, doesn't any matrix bear inside itself the potential to be a Kraus operator)?

Comment: I use "t" because the \dag command did not work. Thank you, it must be a typo.